# How to debug the error message "abort() has been called"?

Tags: c++

There is no red line under the code. When I start without debugging, after I entered the email, a failure is popped up, "abort() has been called". How can I debug this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string email;
    bool good = false;
    while (good == false)
    {
    there:
        cout << "Email is ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, email);
        cout << email.length();
        int a;
        for (int q = 0; q <= email.length(); q++)
        {
            char x = email.at(q);
            int count = 0;
            while (x == '@')
            {
                a = 1;
                count++;
            }
            if (count > 1)
            {
                a = 0;
            }
        }
        if ((email.at(0) == '@') || (email.at(email.length()) == '@') || (a == 0))
        {
            cout << "Input is invalid. One character ‘@’ must be found. Moreover, there must be some characters before and after the character ‘@’." << endl;
            goto there;
        }
        else
        {
            good = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Start it with debugging and you should see where you're accessing something out of bounds.

Comment: Indices in array-like entities in C++ are 0 based, i.e., you’d have indices 0,..., length-1.

Comment: Why exactly do you need the goto?

Comment: Likely because they don't know about `continue`

Comment: I have debugged your program. There are a few problems:
1) email.length()-1 is the maximum index that can be used. Replace with q < email.length() in the for loop,
2) if the string is of length zero the email.at(0) will fail assertion,
3) should be email.at(email.length()-1))
I would write the solution a different way but with you style these are the causes of program crashes.

Comment: Pro-tip: many questions on _Stack Overflow_ use the phrase "please help me do X" when what they really meant was "please do my work for me". It's a misleading phrase, because to ask for help ought to mean that both the asker and the assistant each do some share of the work; what happens in practice is that the assistant does it all (or that becomes the unfair expectation of the asker).

Comment: This is likely to be the motivation of eight people who downvoted your question, and it was not helped by the "thx" at the end. We get a lot of `gimme da codez, kthxbai` here, and it is deleted pretty quickly. You may not have intended to give the impression I describe here, but perhaps now I have explained it, you'll word future questions in a way that does not fall into this trap. Hope this helps!

Comment: i think you should first change `for (int q = 0; q <= email.length(); q++)` to `for (int q = 0; q < email.length(); q++)`

Comment: guys, thx for helping me. I finally understand that cin.ignore() ignore my first character of my input and makes the length of string minus 1, thus leads to the problems of array, resulting in the error message. btw, @halfer . thx for your words. Actually i have debugged by myself before posting, but i still could not figure out what cause the problem. So i posted the code here to ask people figure out what cause the problem.

Comment: OK, but if you do not show any debugging, readers will assume you have not done any. Always show your efforts - it can really save a question for downvotes/closure.

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of problems in your code. First check my comment for one about your for-loop.

Next, in your for loop, you while-loop will be an infinite loop if the first character is indeed '@', as you would never break out of it.

```
        while (x == '@')
        {
            a = 1;
            count++;
        }
```